# Building a JSON string from act_as_tree tree

Tags: ruby

I am new in learning Ruby. In a program, I have used [acts_as_tree](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_tree/2.1.0/ActsAsTree/ClassMethods) to build an organization tree from a hierarchical table. Now, I wish to build a JSON string from the data contained in tree nodes. In the JSON output, each parent node will have an attribute called 'children' that will contain array of the records of the children of the parent node. To build such a JSON string, manually traversing the entire tree can be an option. But, what I wish to know is if there is any other way more elegant than this.

Comment: Please post any code you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this on another project, but using a home grown tree structure.  You'll need to override `as_json` on your object.  I thought that doing something like:

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  super(opts.merge(include: :children))
end
```

would be sufficient, and it might be - maybe I have something else wrong with my codebase that prevents it from working.  However, I was able to do it like this:

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  super(opts).merge(children: children.as_json)
end
```

This essentially creates a recursive `as_json` call since `as_json` will be called on all child elements, which will then have their `as_json` method called on their children and so forth.

Comment: Should I define `as_json` inside the class creating `ActiveRecord` model?

Comment: Yeah, it's inside of the same model that has the `acts_as_tree` call.

Comment: Why are we overriding `as_json`, not `to_json`?

Comment: `to_json` returns a string, while `as_json‘ returns a serializable hash that we can merge and manipulate. The latter also gets called when calling the former.  The correct way to override default JSON serialization is via overriding `as_json`.

Comment: The code you provided seems to work fine. Thanks. Can you please tell me if I want to recur `as_json` call upto a cetain depth, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the JSON library?

try:

```
require 'json'
your_object.root.to_json
```

or even just:

```
require 'json'
your_object.to_json
```

You could probably create a Hash and Arrays from the root, or the object, and the children...

```
{root: your_object, children: your_object.children }.to_json
```

Since I never used the `acts_as_tree` library, I'm not sure if this would help.

Comment: I already did. But that gives the root node details, that's it.

Comment: Sounds like a great start. I updated the answer to see if extrapolating from what you already have can help.